# how to support TLS1.2 on WebView control in Android API 16?

Tags: android, ssl, webview

I have an Android app that needs to work from API16. Basically the app contains a webview control and access a third party site. Well, the problem is that that site will start working only with TLS1.2 and will disable oldest security protocols and webview from API 16 to 19 doesnt support it. I need to know if there is a way I can make it work without replacing the control completely.

Things I have tried:

1. I created a custom class and made it inherit from WebViewClient class. I overrode shouldinterceptrequest method to intercept the request and make the call using my own socket (configured to support TLS1.2) which works fine for GET calls but it doesnt for POST calls.
2. I know TLS1.2 is supported but its not part of the default protocols.

   ```
   SSLContext.getDefault().getDefaultSSLParameters(); // API16 returns SSLv3, TLSv1 
   SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters(); // API16 returns SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2
   ```

I tried to find a way to enable it from the Context but there is no option to do that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!